# How to get GET data for the current url when a page loads in jquery

Tags: jquery, url, get, jquery-load

I have a url like `/accounts/?status=done`

So on load of the document i want to get the `current url` and `GET data` like status=done

so below is my code which can able to get the current url, but not the GET data

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function() {
                             //alert("window load occurred!");
                             var pathname = window.location.pathname;
                     console.log(pathname);
                     $.get(pathname,function(data){ console.log(data) });
                    });
</script>
```

So how to get the current url and GET data like ?status=done in jquery on loading of page ?

**Edit**

So i have edited according to the link provided here as below and still its unable to print the query string parameters

```
<script>
            function getParameterByName(name) {
                console.log(name+"......................");
                          name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                          var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                          results = regex.exec(location.search);
                          return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
                            }

  $(window).load(function() {
                             //alert("window load occurred!");
                             var pathname = window.location.pathname;
                         console.log(pathname+"hurayyyyy");
                     console.log(pathname);
                     var res = getParameterByName(window.location.pathname)
                 console.log(res+"oooppppppppppppssssssssssss");
                    });


</script>
```

The results was just like below

[image]

Comment: possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Comment: I have added an edit, please move make me move in a right direction ..

Answer (score 1):

How can i get the current URL of the page in jquery

```
var URL = $(location).attr('href');
```

Now the variable URL contains the current address of your Browser location.

Answer (score 0):

Asign the value through server side language on javascript variable and then use that variable value in your javascript code.

here is PHP server side language code:-

```
var get_status = "<?php echo $_GET['status']; ?>";
    if(get_status== 'done'){
    //here is your code
    }
```

Comment: Mark code in your answers properly, please. There is a button that looks like `{}` when you write an answer. Select a code and press that button.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this:

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        var URL = $(location).attr('href');
        var GET_ARR = URL.split('/');
        if($.inArray('?status=done', GET_ARR)){
            //do something
        }                      
    });
</script>
```